# Match and merge 3 matrices into one matrix of 3 columns

Tags: r, matrix, merge, match

I would like to merge 3 matrices (lat, lon and obs) into one unique matrix (or data.frame) where each value matches with the correspondent ones.

Let's suppose I have the following matrices:

```
latitude_m

   lat lat lat
lat 3   12  4
lat 5   45  9
lat 12  33  1

longitude_m

   lon lon lon
lon 1   34  3
lon 23   5  1
lon 2    2  9

observations_m

   obs obs obs
obs 45  13   6
obs 22   4   9
obs  2   1  10
```

How can I get the following:

```
lat lon obs
3    1   45
5   23   22
12   2    2
12  34   13
45   5    4
33   2    1
4    3    6
9    1    9
1    9   10
```

Thanks

Comment: `data.frame(lat = c(latitude_m), lon=c(longitute_m), obs  = obsercations_m)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Akruns solution works well, but just in case there is some information associated with the index of each value it might be wise to store it as an array.

```
set.seed(1)
lon <- matrix(sample(-180:180, 9), 3)
lat <- matrix(sample(-90:90, 9), 3)
obs <- matrix(round(runif(9)*9, 1), 3)

library(abind)
arr <- abind(lon, lat, obs, along=3)
```

If you then want to collapse it down to two dimensions it is as easy as resetting `dim()`

```
dim(arr) <- c(9, 3)
arr
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]  -85  -79  3.4
# [2,]  -47  -53  7.0
# [3,]   25  -59  8.4
# [4,]  145   32  1.9
# [5,] -108  -23  5.9
# [6,]  139   45  1.1
# [7,]  155   -3  2.4
# [8,]   53   34  3.5
# [9,]   42   81  0.1
```